# Images from a specific directory not delivered via SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, ssl, wicket

I am running a Wicket web application in Apache Tomcat on two separate servers. When the application runs on server #1, all of the images are delivered without errors or warnings on both http: and https:, so I don't think there is a problem with the html file.  When I run the same application on server #2, all of the images are delivered over http:, but some of the images are giving 404 Not Found when delivered over https:.

For example:

- /path/image1.png and is delivered successfully over http and https.
- /path/some/sub/directory/image2.png is delivered over http, but not delivered over https.

More specifically, if I request https://domain/path/some/sub/directory/image2.png, I get a 404 error.  But if I specify the port and request https://domain:8443/path/some/sub/directory/image2.png the image is delivered.

As the images both work on the first server, I suspect there is some problem with my Apache configuration on the second server.  I can't find any directives specific to the functioning or malfunctioning directories in the apache2.conf, httpd.conf, or .htaccess files.

Where should I look to find the directive that allows image1 to be delivered successfully so that I can copy the rules for image 2?

:::EDIT:::

I found the following directives in extras/httpd-ssl.conf.  We are using varnish to cache static content.

```
# Terminate SSL here and pass everything to Varnish
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://128.138.128.89:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://128.138.128.89:80/
```

This is running on Linux Mint on Oracle VirtualBox if that matters.

Comment: What are your Apache HTTPD proxy settings?

Comment: @martin-g I posted the only proxy directives I could find above

Comment: There are no rules for port 8443. Add them and see whether it helps.